# How can you get an Azure Function to run in an App Service, rather than Consumption mode?, i.e. what are the missing WebJobs attributes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

How can you get an Azure Function to run in an App Service, rather than Consumption mode?, i.e. what are the missing WebJobs attributes?

I have an existing Function App which works fine, but want to run it in an App Service, rather than Consumption plan

Tried deploying to a new App Service ...

The two functions which are just GET endpoints worked fine

But the POST endpoint throws a 500 error ... `Can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?`

```
{
  "id": "5887571d-c993-4e0e-a275-c5ebf34242f8",
  "requestId": "2e9378e4-ceac-491f-8dd7-dd08acb94324",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "'CheckUrl' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. 
               Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no fundamental differences between the two, other than billing and how long processes stay alive. So I suspect that whatever issue you are encountering is not directly related to it running in an App Service Plan.

Try deploying identical bits to both a fresh new Consumption and App Service Plans apps to verify this.